# Detecting duplicate/very similar passages of text

Tags: java, lucene, text-classification, document-classification

I'm writing an application allowing users to add quotes to a database, searchable via Lucene. Is it better to use TF-IDF & cosine similarity to determine if a quote is very similar to another, or the Damerau–Levenshtein distance?

E.g.

> Two roads diverged in a wood and I - I took the one less traveled by, and that has made all the difference.

vs

> 2 roads diverged in a wood and I took the one less travelled by, and that made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>#I dont think you can really answer this...</strike>

... but you could try to structure them similarly:

### Possible methods:

- Make both inputs lowerCase!
- Check if one of them contains the other and vice versa
- Remove characters that arent really needed. ("-" or ";")
- You can also try to find a way to switch the words around until the match but I wouldnt do that

## I found this:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Yup, I plan to run the quotes through a StandardAnalyzer and then compare that...

Comment: I'm wondering though if using the TF-IDF will give better results of similarity (in the examples I showed) vs string distance metrics...